# Find range of values for a square's area.

Tags: geometry, area

This is question is from my practice final exam.

The perimeter of a square is to be between 20 meters and 60 meters. What is the range of values for its area?

Comment: what have you tried? Do you know what the area of a square is in terms of its perimeter?

Comment: @DanRust I have no idea how to set up the problem.

Comment: What do you think the side length of a square with a perimeter of $20$ (or $60$) would be? Can you use that value to determine the area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If a square has perimeter $P$ then, as each of its four edges must have the same length $l$, and the perimeter is the sum of the lengths of the edges, from $$P=4l$$ we get $$l=P/4.$$

We know that the area $A$ of a square with side-length $l$ is $A=l^2$.

Can you substitute the first equation $l=P/4$ into the second equation $A=l^2$ so that we have an equation relating the area $A$ and the perimeter $P$?

Now consider the value of the area if the perimeter is at its minimum $P=20$ and its maximum $P=60$.

Comment: After doing the calculations this is the answer I got. 25 < A < 225.

Comment: You're correct.